# java.net.URL/URI consider an invalid URL as valid

Tags: java, url

Not all invalid urls will be consider as invalid by java.net.URL/URI

An example: http:www.google.com

Is it a bug or is it a feature?

Or is maybe the string above a valid url?

Comment: That's not a valid URI. Perhaps you mean `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: If you paste that on the browser it works , and transforms it to https://www.google.com/ , maybe there is a similar functionality

Comment: No, I mean http:www.google.com. And yes, I know. it is an invalid URI, but it can be parsed by both java.net.URL and java.net.URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `//`, the URL is treated as a *relative* URL, that needs a context to be useful.

If you try using it, you'll get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
```

Comment: thanks for explanation. I'm now using the java.net.URL to check if the given URL is valid in general and then check if it has host or not.